# Error creating simple servlet/ejb program

Tags: jsp, tomcat, servlets, ejb

I am encountering some errors while trying to execute a simple ejb/servlet application.The server I am using is tomcat 7.0 using eclipse as an IDE.

Heres the servlet

```
public class CurrencyServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @EJB
    CurrencyEjb ejb;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public CurrencyServlet() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    public void init(ServletConfig config){

    }
    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    double result=0;    
    String currency=request.getParameter("amount");
    double cur=Double.parseDouble(currency);
    if(cur>0)
    {
        if((request.getParameter("currency").equals("yen")))
                {
            result=ejb.toYen(cur);
                }
        else
            result=ejb.toDollars(cur);
    }
    PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
    out.println("Your value is worth:"+result);
    out.close();
    }

}


The currencyejb file is as follows.

import javax.ejb.*;
@Stateless
public class CurrencyEjb implements CurrencyMethods{
public double toYen(double request)
{
    double result=request*115.3100;
    return result;
}
@Override
public double toDollars(double request)
{
    double result=request*0.0071;
    return result;
}

}
```

My web.xml file is as given

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>CurrenyConverter</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
 <servlet>
        <servlet-name>CurrencyServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>CurrencyServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>CurrencyServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/CurrencyServlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

The errors which I get is as follows

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating servlet class CurrencyServlet
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:380)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:243)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:166)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:288)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)


root cause 

javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name CurrencyServlet is not bound in this Context
    org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:803)
    org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:159)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:380)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:243)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:166)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:288)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first glance, this part seems problematic:

```
@EJB
CurrencyEjb ejb;
```

You are trying to perform EJB injection, which is not possible in Tomcat. If your EJB CurrencyEjb is deployed somewhere else (i.e. within **application server**), then you can access it, but not through EJB injection. Namely, Tomcat is not EJB container, it is just servlet container, that is - you cannot deploy EJBs on it. Have a look at [Glassfish](http://glassfish.java.net/), [JBoss](http://www.jboss.org) or [TomEE](http://tomee.apache.org/) (an extension of Tomcat with full Java EE support) and try to deploy your project there.

Answer (score 3):

Well thats because , Tomcat is a web container and not an application container.
You should deploy your code in an application servers like 
- [Glassfish](http://glassfish.java.net/),
 [JBoss](http://www.jboss.org/) 
,[TomEE](http://tomee.apache.org/), [WebLogic Application Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebLogic_Application_Server) ,[WebSphere Application Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_WebSphere_Application_Server) etc

Check out the following links for more info

- [Web Server, Web Container & Application Server](http://geekexplains.blogspot.in/2008/06/web-server-web-container-application.html)
- [web server vs app server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5481902/web-server-vs-app-server)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
<servlet>
       <servlet-name>CurrencyServlet</servlet-name>
       <servlet-class>CurrencyServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
```

It may happen cause you not set the full servlet path, including package.
For example:

```
<servlet-class>your.full.package.CurrencyServlet</servlet-class>
```