# Is Apache Tomcat a Web server or an application server

Tags: java, apache, web-services, jakarta-ee, tomcat7

Is Apache Tomcat a web server or an application server?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5481902/web-server-vs-app-server

Comment: It's kind of both.  It will serve web pages.  It is also a simple Java EE application server.  If you add more libraries to Tomcat, it will serve more complicated Java EE apps (I think that's what JBoss does).

Comment: It's neither. Without any additional libraries it is just a web container for serving servlets and JSPs. It can serve static files, but you shouldn't confuse it with real web server like for example Apache. And it also lacks libraries required by application server.

Answer (score 2):

Appache tomcat is only servlet container (as jetty). Real application server is Glassfish, Jboss...

Answer (score 0):

Apache Tomcat is webserver with a servlet container. It is not full fledged application server like jboss or websphere. However, latest versions like tomcat 7 are more than the webserver. it is webcontainer.